# python lib html_requests html.render() don't get all elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, request

```
import requests_html

url = 'https://www.crous-bordeaux.fr/restaurant/resto-u-pierre-bidart/'

s = requests_html.HTMLSession()
r = s.get(url)
r.html.render()

print(r)
```

<strike>J'aimerais récupérer le menu de mon restaurant  universitaire, mais j'arrive pas à récupérer l'éléments `content-repas`. The page that is retrieved by my script is incomplete.</strike>
I would like to pick up the menu from my university restaurant, but I can't get the `content-repas` items. The page that is retrieved by my script is incomplete.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not in English.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to save your question by translating it to English - next time please post your questions in English, clearly state your problem, and also read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, `requests-html` package can be considered unmaintained, as last release was more than 3 years ago: Released: Feb 17, 2019

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access that menu with Requests. here is an example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.crous-bordeaux.fr/restaurant/resto-u-pierre-bidart/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
menu = soup.select_one('div[id="menu-repas"]').text
print(menu)
```

Result in terminal:

```
Menu du mardi 25 octobre 2022

Petit déjeunerPas de service
DéjeunerVENTE A EMPORTER OU SUR PLACE MIDIENTREECordon bleuPoisson à la bordelaiseBoulette soja tomateBlé pilaf sauce tomateHaricots vertsDESSERTVENTE A EMPORTER SOIRmenu non communiqué
DînerPas de service



Menu du mercredi 26 octobre 2022

Petit déjeunerPas de service
DéjeunerVENTE A EMPORTER OU SUR PLACE MIDIENTREEDos de colin d'Alaska sauce basquaiseEmincé de porcPurée de potironHaricots platsDESSERTVENTE A EMPORTER SOIRmenu non communiqué
DînerPas de service



Menu du jeudi 27 octobre 2022

Petit déjeunerPas de service
DéjeunerVENTE A EMPORTER OU SUR PLACE MIDIENTREEPoisson meunièreSteak hachéFritesBrocolis ail/persilDESSERTVENTE A EMPORTER SOIRmenu non communiqué
DînerPas de service
```

For Requests' documentation, please visit https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/